# java.util.NoSuchElementException (Runtime error)

Tags: java

When I submit the following code to codeforces.com (http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/3/A):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class A3 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("");
    Scanner t=new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("");
    String a=s.next();
    int y=s.nextInt();
    int x = (int)a.charAt(0);
    String d=t.next();
    int fy=t.nextInt();
    int fx = (int)d.charAt(0);
    int n=0;
    if (Math.abs(fx-x)>Math.abs(fy-y))
    {
        n=Math.abs(fx-x);
    }
    else
    {
        n= Math.abs(fy-y);
    }
    System.out.printf("%d\n",n);
    for (int counter=1;counter<=n;++counter)
    {
        if (fx<x)
        {
            System.out.printf("L");
            x--;
        }
        else if (fx>x)
        {
            System.out.printf("R");
            x++;
        }
        if (fy<y)
        {
            System.out.printf("D");
            y--;
        }
        else if (fy>y)
        {
            System.out.printf("U");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    s.close();
    t.close();

  }
}
```

, it says that no such element is found although it runs just fine in Eclipse and JCreator IDE. So can someone let me know where I did wrong? Thanks in advance :) 
The complete error code :

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException

at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)

at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1371)

at A3.main(A3.java:10)
```

Comment: Why are you using 2 scanners for the same stream `System.in` ???

Comment: I used 2 scanners since I need to read in 2 line of inputs with nospace as the delimiters  and I don't know any other way to implement it using 1 scanner..

Answer (score 2):

You want to read 2 line of inputs, I believe you can use **BufferedReader** and **StringTokenizer**:

In place of below code:

```
Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("");
Scanner t=new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("");
String a=s.next();
int y=s.nextInt();
int x = (int)a.charAt(0);
String d=t.next();
int fy=t.nextInt();
int fx = (int)d.charAt(0);
```

You can use following:

```
BufferedReader br  = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
StringTokenizer str = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
String a = str.nextToken();
int y = Integer.parseInt(str.nextToken);
int x = (int)a.charAt(0);//same as earlier

str = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
String d = str.nextToken();
int fy = Integer.parseInt(str.nextToken);
int fx = (int)d.charAt(0);//same as earlier
```

This should be enough to do what you want, plus it is fast as compared to Scanner.
You can check out [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/fast-io-in-java-in-competitive-programming/) article, it shows different ways to read input in Java, also tells which is better in terms of speed: